# Can you extend a generic class (eg Array) with specific constraints?

Tags: generics, swift

I would like to extend the `Array` class, but only for elements which conform to the `SequenceType` protocol.

The code I would like to write / the code I think would be sensible is:

```
extension Array {
    func flatten<T: SequenceType>() -> [T.Generator.Element] {
        var result = [T.Generator.Element]() // *** [2]

        for seq: T in self { // *** [1]
            for elem in seq {
                result += [elem]
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

However, Swift seems to create two versions of `T`.  I assume one comes from the normal `Array` declaration, and the other from the attempted constraint on my method.

In particular, this means that line [1] gives the lovely error `'T' is not convertible to 'T'`.

Similarly, the line at [2] fails, because in that context Swift does not recognise `T` as having a `.Generator` member (although the return type annotation in the declaration is valid).

I've tried a number of other formulations (including using, eg, `T where T: SequenceType`), but I can't seem to find a way to express this constraint.
Is this possible, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I hope so, but I don't think so.

Comment: An alternative would be `func flatten<T: SequenceType>(array: [T]) -> [T.Generator.Element] {...`

Comment: @jtbandes - I actually thought the same, but trying for a generic version of that function crashes my compiler >< (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194210/what-about-this-code-causes-swift-to-crash)

Comment: Not as of a beta or two ago.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this, as commenters to your question have already stated, is no. However, it's pretty clear from the organization of the Swift standard library that writing a specialized generic function as a method is discouraged. (I suspect that will change as Swift's type system evolves.) For instance, notice that there is no `contains` method of Swift's native array type. **Instead, it is implemented as a global function**, because of the requirement that elements be `Equatable`. This is precisely because of the limitation you encountered: It is not possible to specialize a generic type parameter of the enclosing class in a method, whether it's an extension or not. (This is, in my opinion, a truly unfortunate limitation.)

So, as Swift currently stands, I would "implement" `flatten` by just using `join`, e.g., `join([], arrayOfArrays)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair point from an architectural standpoint.  They seem to have made the decision to go for consistency (aka Python) rather than ease of use/reading (Ruby), which is fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

With Swift 2 this is now possible:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : SequenceType {
    func flatten() -> [Generator.Element.Generator.Element] {
        var result: [Generator.Element.Generator.Element] = []
        for seq in self {
            result += seq
        }
        return result
    }
}

[[1,2,3],[],[2,4,5]].flatten() // [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```

Note though that this specific function isn't so important now that we have flatMap in the library.