# What about this code causes swift to crash?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm playing around with arrays and a `flatten` function in order to wrap my head around how Swift uses generics.

However, the following code gives a generic 'Error running playground' popup, and I can't work out why.

Interestingly, if I put the code into a project and try to compile it, the compiler segfaults.

```
import Cocoa

var arr: [[Int]] = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]

func flatten<S: SequenceType, SS: SequenceType, E where S.Generator.Element == SS, SS.Generator.Element == E>(seq: S) -> [E] {
    var result = [E]()

    for subseq: SS in seq {
        for elem: E in subseq {
            result += [elem]
        }
    }

    return result
}

var flattened = flatten(arr)
println(flattened)
```

Has anyone seen something like this / found a workaround?

Sadly I suspect this might just be a bug with type inference in the beta :(

Comment: "Sadly I suspect this might just be a bug with type inference in the beta" Wouldn't be the first. File a radar.

Comment: @Kevin - is there a way to submit official bug reports for swift?  I can't seem to find it on bugreport.apple.com

Comment: It's on bugreport.apple.com; New > Developer Tools.

Comment: A compiler crash is always a bug, no matter how right or wrong the code is.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely seems to be some sort of bug with Swift generics (it should at least be showing a compile error instead of apparently crashing).

As for a workaround though, this seems to work:

```
func flatten<E>(seq: [[E]]) -> [E] {
    var result = [E]()

    for subseq: [E] in seq {
        for elem: E in subseq {
            result += [elem]
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: While that's handy for some cases (and I had no idea `[[E]]` was valid; that's cool), won't it only work with arrays?  I was interested in a more generic solution for all sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Your `flatten` implementation still crashes the compiler, which I still regard as a bug. However, if you define it like this, it works:

```
func flatten<S: SequenceType, E where S.Generator.Element: SequenceType, S.Generator.Element.Generator.Element == E>(seq: S) -> [E] {
    var result = [E]()
    for subseq: S.Generator.Element in seq {
        for elem: E in subseq {
            result += [elem]
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

This achieves your goal of working with any `SequenceType`, not just arrays. (In fact, I wish we could return an even more general type than `[E]`. If I were back in C# land, I'd return `IEnumerable<E>`, the closest equivalent of `SequenceType`, to get even more sexy encapsulation. Swift is a bit leakier.)

Comment: There is a more general type than `[E]` – check out `ExtensibleCollectionType`.

Comment: Yes, and `SequenceType` is even more general than that. But my point is that you can't return `SequenceType` or `ExtensibleCollectionType` from the function above as it is currently written, though I'd love to be proven wrong on that. :)

Comment: `func flatten<S: SequenceType, E: ExtensibleCollectionType where S.Generator.Element: SequenceType, E.Generator.Element == S.Generator.Element.Generator.Element>(source: S) -> E { var result = E(); for subseq in source { for elemen in subseq { result.append(elemen) } }; return result  }`

Comment: When I try that, it says, "Expression does not conform to type $T22`.

Comment: Never mind, needed to give it some evidence: `let xs: [Int] = flatten([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])`. Well done.

Comment: This works only because the `ExtensibleCollectionType` protocol is defined to require `init()`. Too bad `SequenceType` isn't similarly defined.

Comment: `SequenceType` is too abstract for that – but you could return a `SequenceOf` that computed the values lazily from the input sequence.